# (linux)Socket returns 0

Tags: c++, linux, sockets

Though i know that 0 is a valid file descriptor in linux & can be returned by the call to socket(), but the subsequent call to bind or setsockopt fails with errorcode:88 (operation on non-socket).
Also i am not able to understand where i might have closed my stdin file descriptor in order to get a socket value as 0.
Here is my code snippet.. Its a simple socket class..

```
bool serverHandler::startServer(string strAddress,int port)
{
    //memset(&m_srvAddr,'\0',sizeof(m_srvAddr));
    m_srvSock = -1;
    if(m_srvSock = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0) < 0)
        cout<<"serverHandler: Failed to create server socket."<<endl;
    m_srvAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    m_srvAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(strAddress.c_str());                            
    m_srvAddr.sin_port = htons(port);
    cout<<"Socket value:"<<m_srvSock<<" for "<<strAddress<<" "<<port<<endl;
    if (bind(m_srvSock,(struct sockaddr *) &m_srvAddr,sizeof(m_srvAddr)) < 0)                     
    {
        cout<<"Failed with errno:"<<errno<<endl;
        return false;
    }
    if (listen(m_srvSock, MAX_PENDING) < 0)
    {
        return false;                
    }
}
```

And the call to this function is a simple:

```
srvHandler.startServer("127.0.0.1",7878);
```

I have used the same way to write down many socket programs, not getting what is wrong in this one.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(m_srvSock = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0) < 0)
```

Is not correct since `<` is evaluated before `=` (lower precedence), you need to add parenthesis:

```
if((m_srvSock = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0)) < 0)
```

If you're using GCC, you should set `-W -Wall` options to get `warning` for these kind of mistakes, with MVSC use at least `/W4`.

Comment: Thanks for the correction, but in anycase the value of m_srvSock is zero & it will pass the check.
I have a cout which displays the value as 0.

Comment: It got resolved after i changed the order of my "sockaddr_in" members initialisation.(initialised port before s_addr)
I don't know what is the concept behind it, any lights on this ?

Comment: Kratos, there isn't any light behind it.  That isn't your problem.

Comment: Yeah true, but initially i was getting the file descriptor as 0 , after doing this, i started getting normal values.. I don't know how..

Answer (score 0):

> I am not able to understand where i might have closed my stdin file descriptor in order to get a socket value as 0.

I just discovered how this was happening in a project of mine. Consider this situation:

```c
int sock;

void init()
{
  sock = 0;
}

void start()
{
  sock = socket(...);
}

void cancel()
{
  close(sock);
}
```

This works fine so long as `cancel` is always called at most once per `start`, and you never have a call to `init` coming in-between.

In my case, an error handler was calling `cancel` after `init` had  been called, which was causing `close(0)` and therefore closing stdin.